# Flood game implementation

Tags: jquery, game, coffeescript

There is the [implementation of flood game](https://github.com/kharandziuk/flood-coffee) on my GitHub.

The app.coffee is the main part of project:

```
class Square
  colors = [
    'orange',
    'green',
    'red',
    'blue',
    'violet',
    'yellow',
  ]
  constructor: (@game, @node)->
    @node.on 'click', =>
      @game.flood(@color)

  reset: ->
    @controlled = false
    color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
    @setColor(color)

  setColor: (color)->
    @node.removeClass(@color)
    @color = color
    @node.addClass(@color)


class Game
  DIMENSION = 14
  SIZE = DIMENSION * DIMENSION
  constructor: ($tbody)->
    @limit = 25
    @grid = []
    for i in [0...DIMENSION]
      $tr = $ '<tr/>'
      $tbody.append $tr
      @grid.push []
      for j in [0...DIMENSION]
        $td = $('<td/>').html('&nbsp;')
        $tr.append $td
        @grid[i].push(new Square(@, $td))
    @top = @grid[0][0]
    @reset()

  reset: ->
    for i in [0...DIMENSION]
      for j in [0...DIMENSION]
        @grid[i][j].reset()
    @top = @grid[0][0]
    @top.controlled = true
    @flood(@top.color)
    @setTurnCounter(0)

  setTurnCounter: (counter)->
    $counter = $ '#count'
    @turn = counter
    $counter.toggleClass 'bad', @turn > @limit
    $('#counter-used').text(@turn)


  flood: (color)->
    if @top.color is color
      return
    @setTurnCounter(@turn + 1)
    @_flood(0, 0, color, [])
    if @hasWon()
      setTimeout(
        =>
          @decreaseLimit()
          @reset()
        2000
      )
  decreaseLimit: ()->
    @expected--



  _flood: (i, j, color, checked)->
    if i < 0 or j < 0 or i == DIMENSION or j == DIMENSION
      return
    cur = @grid[i][j]
    if cur.controlled or cur.color is color
      if cur in checked
        return
      cur.setColor(color)
      cur.controlled = true
      checked.push cur
      @_flood(i-1, j, color, checked)
      @_flood(i+1, j, color, checked)
      @_flood(i, j-1, color, checked)
      @_flood(i, j+1, color, checked)

  hasWon: ->
    for i in [0...DIMENSION]
      for j in [0...DIMENSION]
        if not @grid[i][j].controlled
          return false
    return true

(($, Game)->
  tbody = $('tbody')
  game = new Game(tbody)
  btnRestart = $('#btn-restart')
  btnRestart.on 'click', (e)->
    e.preventDefault()
    game.reset()

)(jQuery, Game)
```

I build assets with Grunt and use grunt-serve as a simple HTTP server.

P.S.: I use styles from another [implementation of this game but based on Knockout.js.](http://evanhahn.com/tape/flood/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall, it's not bad. I only have some minor observations on the code itself:

- You're setting, and re-setting `@top` in both the constructor and `reset`.
- `SIZE` isn't used for anything.
- Why does `reset` call `flood`? As far as I can tell, there's no need at all.
- Doesn't seem like `decreaseLimit` has a point.
- You could postfix a couple of `if`/`unless` statements and cut down on indentation.
- in `_flood` the `if i < 0 or j < 0 or i == DIMENSION or j == DIMENSION` check could be written as:

  ```
  return unless 0 <= i < DIMENSION and 0 <= j < DIMENSION
  ```

  or you could simply skip it in favor of trying the coordinates and checking afterward:

  ```
  square = @grid[i]?[j]
  return unless square?
  ```
- When looping through the `@grid` (in `reset` and `hasWon`) there's no need to use a `[0...DIMENSION]` range. You can just use regular CoffeeScript `for...in` loops:

  ```
  for row in @grid
    for square in row
      # do something with square...
  ```
- The IIFE at the end could be written more idiomatically using the `do` keyword

  ```
  do ($ = jQuery, Game) ->
    ...
  ```

Structurally, I have a few notes:

- You inject both the `Game` object and a `td` element into `Square`, so Square doesn't really have that much to do. In fact, the first thing it does is set an event listener on the element that the game object created, and set it to call back to the game object. It just seems a roundabout way to set things up.
  I'd probably move the `td` creation to `Square`.
- You pass a `tbody` element to the `Game` constructor, which is nice. But `Game` also directly accesses `#count` and `#counter-user`. So it's not really decoupled from the markup at all.
- Somewhat similarly: You pass in `jQuery` as `$` in the IIFE that kicks things off. That's a perfectly good pattern. However, `Game` just uses `$` "raw". So you're sort of half-way following the pattern.

[Here's a (simplified) refactored version](http://jsfiddle.net/eztgfL5y/), just for fun.

Comment: Thanks! It's a really nice answer. But:
`square = @grid[i]?[j]
return unless square?`
looks like magic for me. Is it really nice to use those magic features of a language?

Comment: @kharandziuk `?` "absorbs" `null`/`undefined`. If you just write `@grid[-1][-2]` (or some other invalid coordinates) you'll get an error, because `@grid[-1]` is undefined, and you can't say `undefined[-2]`. But the `?` will protect you from that. In plain JS, it could be written as `square = this.grid[i] ? this.grid[i][j] : null` followed by `if(!square) return`

Comment: @kharandziuk And yes, it's very nice - when it makes sense. For instance, let's say you want to print a `Person` object with an optional `lastName` property, and you want to make the last name uppercase. Then you could do `person.lastName?.toUpperCase()`. It's just a shorthand for first checking, and then using a property. Check [the docs](http://coffeescript.org/#operators) under "The existential operator": "The accessor variant of the existential operator `?.` can be used to soak up null references in a chain of properties"

Comment: Maybe, I don't understand something:
`grid[i]? # check that i-th element exists and returns bool` and 
`grid[i]?[j] # takes j-th element of bool`
How does it work?

Comment: @kharandziuk The semantics aren't the same. If you just use `foo?`, yes, you get a boolean. But, as I quoted from the docs in my earlier comment, the `?.` (or in this case `?[]`) operator is a variant of that. Something like `foo?.bar` should be read as "if `foo?` is true (i.e. `foo` exists), then access `foo`'s `bar` property"

Comment: @kharandziuk No prob. Added a link to a (simplified) refactored version - just for fun